# How to perform a rolling restart on a docker swarm service?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is this possible? I don't want to use rolling update as I just want to restart the service

Comment: Did you try docker swarmkit?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out there is a flag `--force` to serve this purpose:

`docker service update --force <service_name>`

Comment: You should add --update-delay flag so that the second service will be restarted after the first service restart is complete